# Different search paths when installing Ruby via RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet

I am using Puppet together with Librarian Puppet. Puppet is installed via the system's package manager, Librarian Puppet via Ruby gem. It only works when I install Ruby (1.9.3) via Debian's package manager. When I use RVM with the identical or another version (>= 1.9.3), I get an error from Librarian, saying that it cannot find puppet. Line 4 `require 'puppet'` in `local.rb`causes the problem in Librarian. The puppet gem-based installation is not recommended and I don't want to do it that way. After some hours debugging, I found out that Ruby's search path differs when you use the package manager or RVM. Using RVM with Ruby 2.1.2, I get:

```
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
```

The `puppet.rb`is located at `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby`. This path is part of the search path if I install Ruby via Debian's package manager!

```
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby
    ...
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
```

Is there any solution without installing puppet via gem?

Comment: If you install the `puppet` gem via RVM, it should not interfere with the Debian package, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

librarian-puppet needs the puppet gem to parse the dependencies' Modulefile when using git and path modules. Not for Forge modules though

https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet/blob/master/lib/librarian/puppet/source/local.rb#L8
https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet/pull/62